# How to force an update of WordPress core to a newer minor version, using the Dashboard?

Tags: updates, automatic-updates

It would save substantial time to have an efficient method of forcing a WordPress core update to the latest minor version, using the Dashboard so that cPanel or an equivalent isn't needed.

Minor version updates do generally install automatically, so let's assume for this question that they are configured not to (an alternative reason might be that they're failing to install automatically for some reason... bonus points for covering this?).

Does anyone have any methods to do this? I've looked for a plugin to no avail.

Comment: Just remove the reason that prevents the updates. Since you didn't tell us what that reason is, we can't answer your question.

Comment: @fuxia, surely it's not unreasonable to assume for this question that automatic updates are just configured off?

Comment: Yes, but _how?_ And the simple answer is: remove that configuration.

Comment: And what is that reason? Sometimes it makes sense that all automatic updates are disabled - for example then the code is managed via VCS, or when you have some other tools to manage it. In such cases you can’t just “remove the configuration” - it was there for some reason.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular Do you have access to WP CLI on your server? It's easy with it, ex. wp core update --version=3.1 --force https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/update/ Then you can use other plugins to disable automatic updates (Easy Plugin Updates for example)